# Can I set disabled the device interaction with the IoT Hub to use Azure IoT Hub device provisioning service?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, provisioning

I use Azure IoT hub DPS to register devices.
Can I set Disabled IoT device status when register Device from DPS?
How to do that?

[I want to set this status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5Rmy.png)

> {   "deviceId": "test",   "etag": "AAAAAAAAAAE=",   "deviceEtag":
>   "NTI1OTc3Nzkx",   **"status": "disabled",**   "statusUpdateTime":
>   "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",   "connectionState": "Disconnected",
>   "lastActivityTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
>   "cloudToDeviceMessageCount": 0,   "authenticationType": "sas",
>   "x509Thumbprint": {
>       "primaryThumbprint": null,
>       "secondaryThumbprint": null   },   "version": 2,   "properties": {
>       "desired": {
>         "$metadata": {
>           "$lastUpdated": "2020-01-08T15:09:56.0402103Z"
>         },
>         "$version": 1
>       },
>       "reported": {
>         "$metadata": {
>           "$lastUpdated": "2020-01-08T15:09:56.0402103Z"
>         },
>         "$version": 1
>       }   },   "capabilities": {
>       "iotEdge": false   } }

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You want to register a device with DPS and have it added to the hub in a disabled state? You can't do that.

Comment: It would be better if your answer is complete, may be give the steps and/or how that can be done

Comment: I was specific. It can't be done. You can always disable it later via the portal but that really doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, I was hoping to get at least the link to some tutorials on how to do it. Thanks